# Should Amazon RDS SQL Server 2017 Web Edition Max Memory settings be different from that of a locally installed instance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, memory

We have an Amazon RDS SQL Server Web Edition on Windows Server 2012 with 2 processors and 8GB RAM.
Should I configure the Max Memory similar to that of an instance on a local server i.e keeping back 3-4GB for OS, memory pool etc. or does RDS require a different calculation?

Comment: I can't answer you, but bear in mind AWS Lambda _serverless_ facilities are actually run by AWS instances running the same Amazon Linux your EC2 instances run, and that probably a very similar thing happens at RDS instances.

Answer (score 1):

No, I wouldn't treat this any differently than you would an on-prem instance with regards to max server memory.  The Windows Server 2012 box is almost certainly a VM, but hopefully Amazon is a managing that well to avoid [VM problems](https://erikdarlingdata.com/2019/08/looks-like-a-vm-problem/).

I would definitely reserve 3 GB at minimum for the OS and other overhead.